# AmiBroker AFL code - Shorts not firing

Tags: stocks, trading, stockquotes

I am replicating some code that I wrote in C# in AmiBroker (I'm new to AFL).  This code triggers the Longs, but never fires a short.  The price data has plenty of shorts (proved by C# code).  What am I missing?  Shorts are essentially the reverse of Longs.

```
Buy =   EMA(  Close , 60 ) > Ref( EMA(  Close , 60 ) , -2 )
AND ref(Close, -2) < Ref( EMA(  Close , 15 ) , -2 )
AND Ref(Close, -1) > Ref( EMA(  Close , 15 ) , -1 )
AND Close > EMA(  Close , 15 ) 
AND Close > Open;

Sell =  Close < EMA(  Close , 15 );

Short = EMA(  Close , 60 ) < Ref( EMA(  Close , 60 ) , -2 )
AND Ref( Close, -2 ) > Ref( EMA(  Close , 15 ) , -2 )
AND Ref( Close, -1 ) < Ref( EMA(  Close , 15 ) , -1 )
AND Close < EMA(  Close , 15 ) 
AND Close < Open;

Cover = Close > EMA(  Close , 15 );
```

Comment: What's AmiBroker? What's AFL? You might get some more answers if you explained what this is all about, and what it has to do with C# programming.

Comment: It's not C# but I don't have sufficient rep to create new tags.  AmiBroker folk will know what it is all about. :)

Comment: Did a search for AmiBroker, and these are some of the tags typically used on questions about that. So you don't get frustrated C# programmers showing up here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D'oh!  The properties of the analyser were set to fire Longs only!  I set it to Longs and Shorts and all is well.